# subclassing UIViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, subclassing

I got confused on subclassing a UIViewController in iOS, I have a parent viewcontroller which conforms the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol (in its private interface inside the implementation file).

```
/* Parent.m */

@interface Parent () <UICollectionViewDataSource>

// this CollectionView is connected to storyboard
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *CollectionView;

@end


@implementation Parent


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.somecount;
}

@end
```

And then I create a child view controller which inherited from parent. The child knows nothing about UICollectionViewDataSource as the datasource implemented in parent's private interface.

```
/* child.h */

@interface child : parent
// nothing was mentioned here that parent has a method to set the count using 'somecount'
@end
```

Then I set the viewcontroller from mainstoryboard as the child view controller.

how come ios get the value from parent's property 'somecount' and set the value for child?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> how come ios get the value from parent's property `somecount` and set the value for child?

A subclass always inherits the properties and methods of its `super` class. They may or may not be public interfaces (you haven't shown us the declaration of `somecount`, so we don't know), but regardless, they are there and will be resolved at runtime (unless you override those methods/properties in the `child`, which you don't appear to be doing). If there are private methods and properties in `parent`, you might not be visible at compile-time from the `child`, but they're still there and will behave properly at runtime.

So, when the scene with the collection view specifies the `child` as the data source for the collection view, if `child` doesn't implement those `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods, it will automatically end up invoking those of the `parent`. Likewise, when any of those methods refer to `somecount`, if the `child` doesn't override it, it again will end up calling the appropriate accessor methods of the `parent`. Bottom line, `child` automatically inherits all of the behaviors, methods, and properties of the `parent`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I tried to debug the application, the first line it goes was in parent:
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *CollectionView;

I thought the reason why it can set value for private property in Parent was because storyboard knows the collectionView was outlet to parent class. 

is there anyway to debug the code on storyboard so that I can figure out where is the starting point and the detailed flow of steps.

thanks.

Comment: let me make my question clear:
1. how to find out the flow of code been called from the start of application, any way to debug from the very beginning of storyboard? i.e.initialising storyboard -- initialise Collection view --initialise collection view's controller -- or initialise Parent first?

2. You mentioned "Bottom line, child automatically inherits all of the behaviors, methods, and properties of the parent." does this mean that child class will has the private properties(declared in parent) as well? but child can't access them at compiling time? how come I can't access my own property?

Comment: here is the link: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Pretty%20Matchismo.zip

have a look at the CardGameViewController and PlayingCardGameViewController, 

thanks

Comment: @Justin 1. You really just have to put breakpoints in any of your relevant methods (both for view controllers and/or app delegate) and single step through them. No, you can't debug from "very beginning of storyboard", itself. 2. Yeah, there are two separate issues: (a) what is publicly visible while editing your `child` source code in Xcode; and (b) what happens at run time. They're two completely different things. And frankly, that's good. "Encapsulation" is a major OO design concept, where the implementation details of one class is isolated from from another classes (even subclasses).

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response and the clear explanation. I want to vote your answer up but I don't have the right to do so as I'm new member here.
--Justin.

Comment: No worries. Incidentally, that project seems to be missing Deck class. Is that possible? So, I can't really test without that. But I can see what those controller classes are doing. Frankly, this strikes me as a slightly contrived example (probably part of the course that's making sure you understand that a subclass can override methods of the super class). You wouldn't generally do it this way unless you had a bunch of different view controllers that shared certain common features, and you just wanted to change a few details for each. But I get what they're trying to do.

Comment: @Justin Unfortunately, it's frowned upon to have prolonged conversations here (and you don't yet have enough reputation for chat), so I'm going to end the comment-based conversation here. Hopefully you have enough to get you going. If you have more questions, just submit a new S.O. question. Good luck.